# insert into if not exists ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access

- Using MS Access 2019
- table_a(id,name)

  ## doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO table_a ( name ) VALUES (@name_)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select name from table_a where name=@name_);
```

> error : Query input must contain at least one table or query

and this doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO table ( name ) select @name_
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select name from table where name=@name_);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `VALUES` you should use `SELECT` but even then Access wouldn't allow `SELECT` without `FROM`.
 
So the workaround is to use after `FROM` a query that returns always exactly 1 row, like:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_a
```

Instead of `MIN()` you could use `FIRST()`.
So your code should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_a([name]) 
SELECT @name_
FROM (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_a) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_a WHERE [name] = @name_);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a unique index on `name`:

```
create unique index unq_t_name on t(name);
```

Your insertion will generate an error if you attempt to insert a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO table ( name ) select @name_
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select name from table where name=@name_);
```